# Axiomatic or rule-based definition of an ordinal scale

Tags: sparql, owl, swrl

I would like to create an [ordinal scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_data) class, to be a sibling class of ["`categorical value specification`" in the ontology of biomedical investigations](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0001930)

Loosely speaking, each item in the scale is "more" than the previous.

I think I will need to indicate the rank or order of each item in my ordinal scale instances.  Also, I would like to enforce that the instances of ordinal scales have one and only one item at each rank, with no gaps.  So an ordinal scale with items ranked `1, 2, 3` would pass reasoning, but a scale with ranks `1,2,2` or `1,2,4` would be considered inconsistent. I guess it could be implemented in OWL or SWRL?  I just don't know how.

Seems like [these guys](https://www.w3.org/2009/12/rdf-ws/papers/ws14) have envisioned this as ordered `rdf:lists`, but I haven't seen an implementation yet.

```
Prefix: : <http://example.com/>
Prefix: dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
Prefix: obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
Prefix: owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
Prefix: rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
Prefix: rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
Prefix: xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>
Prefix: xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

Ontology: <http://example.com/Likert>

AnnotationProperty: rdfs:label

Datatype: owl:rational

Datatype: rdf:PlainLiteral

Datatype: xsd:integer

Datatype: xsd:nonNegativeInteger

ObjectProperty: hasPart

    InverseOf: 
        partOf

ObjectProperty: partOf

    InverseOf: 
        hasPart

DataProperty: hasMaxRank

    Characteristics: 
        Functional

    Domain: 
        ordinalValSpec

    Range: 
        xsd:nonNegativeInteger

    SubPropertyOf: 
        owl:topDataProperty

DataProperty: hasMinRank

    Characteristics: 
        Functional

    Domain: 
        ordinalValSpec

    Range: 
        xsd:nonNegativeInteger

DataProperty: hasRank

    Characteristics: 
        Functional

    Domain: 
        ordinalItem

    Range: 
        xsd:nonNegativeInteger

DataProperty: owl:topDataProperty

Class: obo:OBI_0001933

    Annotations: 
        rdfs:label "value specification"

Class: ordinalItem

    EquivalentTo: 
        partOf only ordinalValSpec

Class: ordinalValSpec

    EquivalentTo: 
        hasPart only ordinalItem,
        hasMaxRank exactly 1 owl:rational,
        hasMinRank exactly 1 owl:rational

    SubClassOf: 
        obo:OBI_0001933

Individual: Dislike

    Types: 
        ordinalItem

    Facts:  
     hasRank  1

Individual: Like

    Types: 
        ordinalItem

    Facts:  
     hasRank  3

Individual: Likert

    Types: 
        ordinalValSpec

    Facts:  
     hasPart  Dislike,
     hasPart  Like,
     hasPart  Neutral

Individual: Neutral

    Types: 
        ordinalItem

    Facts:  
     hasRank  2
```